# How do I set a multilingual site name?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm using a multiligual site in french,english and arabic and i want to set a custom sitename (or logo) for each one,for ex: if my sitename for english is : "one two three" i want it "un deux trois" for frensh version .
Is there anyway to fix that?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**i18n** http://drupal.org/project/i18n provides "Multilingual variables"

As the `site_name` is a config variable, presumably it can be translated.

See also: http://drupal.org/node/313272

**settings.php**

```
/**
 * Multilingual settings
 * 
 * This is a collection of variables that can be set up for each language when i18n is enabled.
 * These are the basic ones for Drupal core, but you can add your own here.
 */
$conf['i18n_variables'] = array(
  // Site name, slogan, mission, etc..
  'site_name',
  'site_slogan',
  'site_mission',
  'site_footer',
  // Different front page for each language
  'site_frontpage',
);
```

Comment: thank you but i'm using the variable 7.x-1.2 and the needed version is 7.x-2.1

Comment: I think i can't update the variable module because it's already used in other modules like i18n

Comment: Can you update i18n?

Comment: it's already in it's perfect stage 7.x-1.7

Comment: The i18n module provides the variable translation

Comment: yes but the problem is that for installing variable translation i need to install variable realm and variable store which the current version 7.x-1.7 is not compatoible with the 7.x-1.7 version of i18n, i need to update it to 7.x-2.x which is impossible because i need to update the whole variable module used by i18n hh, it's an infinite cycle...

Comment: As i know,to update variables i need to unistall i18n which is illogic because the whole site is multilinguistic and i will lose all my data structure